# How to save a cookie after the header has been sent in Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, cookies, web, cgi

I know you send a cookie to a user's browser via the HTTP header, but how do you do this after the header has been sent.  For example you set a value in a form you want to grant session wide scope to.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any template system?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Cookies are only set in the header. HTTP provides no way to set them elsewhere.

If you want to set a cookie based on form data, then you do it in the response to the form submission request.

If you want to use data both for generating a cookie and generating a form, then get that data into a variable before you send the header and use it in both locations.

(You could generate JavaScript to set the cookie in the HTML body … but that would be unnecessarily complex and unreliable).

Comment: Sure you can. You just have to be cagey about it.

Comment: Well, go on then brian, don't leave us hanging.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a cookie after you've already sent a response header, you have to make the client load something else that can set the cookie. This might be through an Ajax response, an image link, or something else. You might fire this off automatically or ask the user to update something.

Comment: Interesting, how exactly would this work without loading a new page?  Can you please give an example of this?

Comment: It would work by loading a new image, or piece of JavaScript or something instead of a new page. You still need to make an extra HTTP request.